# Ember add-ons: what is the recommended way to handle input data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

When writing a (public) ember add-on; what is the recommended format for input data coming from the main ember app? Do you expect ember-data objects, or a simpler data model such as an array for example?

If the add-on accepts ember data objects; any modifications to this data can be persisted to the backend easily, but I'm certain that not everyone uses ember-data. If you don't use ember-data, converting a data model into ember-data's formats is madness.

On the other hand, if the add-on accepts an array (for example) as the input data, then the main ember app using ember-data has to extract the data into this array format for the add-on to use.

I haven't seen any guidance in the Ember docs or elsewhere in the web that I could find.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best Idea is to always use `Ember.get('prop')` in favor of `obj.get('prop')` or `obj.prop`. This notation will work for both, ember objects with CPs, including ember-data objects, and plain JS objects.

The beauty about ember objects and ember arrays is that they *are* normal JS objects/arrays, just with a bit extra.

Hoever I wouldn't rely on a object being an ember object, but if you use `Ember.get` in favor of `obj.get` your code will always work.

Answer (score 0):

If your addon is mainly providing components - then you could stick to KISS convention and keep your components as stupid as possible. For example - instead of passing whole model to component it's better to pass single property etc.

[See KISS principle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

[Smart and Dumb components article from React](https://jaketrent.com/post/smart-dumb-components-react/), but Ember also relies on components.